# Unable to retrieve a token from API request

Tags: python, python-requests, token

I'm trying to take this token from a Chinese website as this image displays, using Python requests lib:

[image]

I'm trying to retrieve this item "acw_sc__v2".
I successfully retrieve the other tokens, but I can't find where or how this one is being generated, I appreciate if someone could find its origin and show me how you did it.

The website URL is:
https://we.51job.com/

The API I found here, searching by "python developer":
https://we.51job.com/pc/search?keyword=python%20developer&searchType=2&sortType=0&metro=

My code:

```
import requests
import json

session = requests.Session()
cookies = session.get("https://oauth.51job.com/ajax/get_token.php?fromdomain=51job_web").cookies

cookie_data = cookies.get_dict()
guid = cookie_data["guid"]
acw_tc = cookie_data["acw_tc"]

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en,en-US;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'From-Domain': '51job_web',
    'Referer': 'https://we.51job.com/pc/search?keyword=python developer&searchType=2&sortType=0&metro=',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'account-id': '',
    'partner': 'www_google_com',
    'property': json.dumps({
        "partner": "www_google_com",
        "webId": 2,
        "fromdomain": "51job_web",
        "frompageUrl": "https://we.51job.com/",
        "pageUrl": "https://we.51job.com/pc/search?keyword=python developer&searchType=2&sortType=0&metro=",
        "identityType": "",
        "userType": "",
        "isLogin": "是",
        "accountid": "",
        "keywordType": ""
    }),
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'Windows',
    'sign': '75f6fe150e9824fa27fe977fe3010da9925090e7af46e301a87fda31dca761c4',
    'user-token': '',
    'uuid': '95473941fbf1c03bfb07abf237130b54',
}

cookies = {
    "Cookie": f"partner=www_google_com; seo_refer_info_2023=%7B%22referUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.google.com%5C%2F%22%2C%22referHost%22%3A%22www.google.com%22%2C%22landUrl%22%3A%22%5C%2Fdefault-e.php%22%2C%22landHost%22%3A%22www.51job.com%22%2C%22partner%22%3Anull%7D; privacy=1693088459; guid={guid}; sajssdk_2015_cross_new_user=1; Hm_lvt_1370a11171bd6f2d9b1fe98951541941=1693088465; nsearch=jobarea%3D%26%7C%26ord_field%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch0%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch1%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch2%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch3%3D%26%7C%26recentSearch4%3D%26%7C%26collapse_expansion%3D; sensorsdata2015jssdkcross=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%2295473941fbf1c03bfb07abf237130b54%22%2C%22first_id%22%3A%2218a33efb7c3ef7-0becd38ad9dd06-26031f51-2073600-18a33efb7c4dd2%22%2C%22props%22%3A%7B%22%24latest_traffic_source_type%22%3A%22%E7%9B%B4%E6%8E%A5%E6%B5%81%E9%87%8F%22%2C%22%24latest_search_keyword%22%3A%22%E6%9C%AA%E5%8F%96%E5%88%B0%E5%80%BC_%E7%9B%B4%E6%8E%A5%E6%89%93%E5%BC%80%22%2C%22%24latest_referrer%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22identities%22%3A%22eyIkaWRlbnRpdHlfY29va2llX2lkIjoiMThhMzNlZmI3YzNlZjctMGJlY2QzOGFkOWRkMDYtMjYwMzFmNTEtMjA3MzYwMC0xOGEzM2VmYjdjNGRkMiIsIiRpZGVudGl0eV9sb2dpbl9pZCI6Ijk1NDczOTQxZmJmMWMwM2JmYjA3YWJmMjM3MTMwYjU0In0%3D%22%2C%22history_login_id%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22%24identity_login_id%22%2C%22value%22%3A%2295473941fbf1c03bfb07abf237130b54%22%7D%2C%22%24device_id%22%3A%2218a33efb7c3ef7-0becd38ad9dd06-26031f51-2073600-18a33efb7c4dd2%22%7D; acw_tc=ac11000116931044463076577e00e1a66347abd27c05bd50135d8dfd35ba92; Hm_lpvt_1370a11171bd6f2d9b1fe98951541941=1693104458; acw_sc__v2=64eab951c4ea897b8bc154952eb19ee3838665e1; JSESSIONID=E270CF9ADEC8A1DE358AC37EB01403C9; search=jobarea%7E%60%7C%21recentSearch0%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FApython+developer%A1%FB%A1%FA2%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21recentSearch1%7E%60020000%A1%FB%A1%FA021000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FAGPT%A1%FB%A1%FA2%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21recentSearch2%7E%60000000%A1%FB%A1%FA000000%A1%FB%A1%FA0000%A1%FB%A1%FA00%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA9%A1%FB%A1%FA99%A1%FB%A1%FA%A1%FB%A1%FA0%A1%FB%A1%FAdata+analyst%A1%FB%A1%FA2%A1%FB%A1%FA1%7C%21; ssxmod_itna=CqAx0DBD9Gu4zrD2lm3itGOmK4xormOlmpax0vei=NDpxBFP4oGQKcLoqASvbHUE3hxahRGS+4mPorBxGLDmKjQcfCPiiDC40rD74irDDxD3kx7PGmDimSjD7OCS9X5ycPDwDlKDgDQIdyxDaDGc7FAu7joasUl5DnpxkbY27D75Dux0HLjExwxDCCSExR29ma4i3AnczMx0OD0IGfxusDB+OngFFf/i=eGb0N7q4Nj+3kG0P5mh4N6biHGDxcY2DDXR3Cj4=HixPmYtDiOa2aYD; ssxmod_itna2=CqAx0DBD9Gu4zrD2lm3itGOmK4xormOlmpxn9Eei=eDloophDj+np1Ldidj93nDYuP4HB64HXQnF2dTi8MKYmy0ALjZ8Hioroi1yAADq+0PWq9UOIw883GxaK6x00K+Iroc0HsVN87q5dRMjnl2XXmD39F3ID1xvEQqA8QMdj7wIpnmT7eRKutmfnYuArqRprgiNi=koN2fbHIeboqleDKuDHD7=DeuDxD==; acw_tc={acw_tc}; acw_sc__v2=64eb709f5c1aa93d711318293708c7e47bee8bd2"

}

response = requests.get(
    'https://we.51job.com/api/job/search-pc?api_key=51job&timestamp=1693104486&keyword=python%20developer&searchType=2&function=&industry=&jobArea=000000&jobArea2=&landmark=&metro=&salary=&workYear=&degree=&companyType=&companySize=&jobType=&issueDate=&sortType=0&pageNum=1&requestId=&pageSize=20&source=1&accountId=&pageCode=sou%7Csou%7Csoulb',
    headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

# Debug information
print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
print("Response Text:", response.text)

try:
    print("JSON Response:", response.json())
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    print("Could not decode JSON.")
```

I do not know if this is the only piece missing for the request to succeed, but apparently it is, whenever I change "acw_sc__v2" with one more updated, this works.

I also realized all of them starts with 64+some numbers.
Very likely it is something encoded, but I have no idea, I tried to decode but didn't work.

Comment: That screenshot is from the regular website, not the API.  Maybe the API just doesn't provide that token?  Does the API documentation say that token should be included?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for reaching out and taking your time to see the code.

Actually if the search engine receives the string "python developer", this url will be generated:
https://we.51job.com/pc/search?keyword=python%20developer&searchType=2&sortType=0&metro=

The one I was searching.
It is an open site to find jobs, I'm doing it for a personal project, so I don't think there is a documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

The `acw_sc__v2` cookie is being set by javascript that comes from the previous `/search-pc?...` request (not shown in your screenshot). After a bunch of other function defs, that response ends with

```js
function setCookie(name,value)
{
  var expiredate=new Date();
  expiredate.setTime(expiredate.getTime()+(3600*1000));
  document.cookie=name+"="+value+";expires="+expiredate.toGMTString()+";max-age=3600;path=/";
}
function reload(x) {setCookie("acw_sc__v2", x);document.location.reload();}
```

I'm not sure where that `reload()` is being called from, though - it's not in that document.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering the question!
The issue with this is that I don't have idea how to even use it in my python code..
I could change it to JS script, I don't have much experience with JS, but even using JS how do I make it return something?
In this case I'll have to get that number and store in some variable, which is something like this: 64eb709f5c1aa93d711318293708c7e47bee8bd2
This piece of code you sent is indeed what is raised when the bash call for that API don't work, I just realized now.

Comment: I would be inclined to do some more hunting around to figure out when/how this newly-defined `reload()` function is called. When you find that, you'll hopefully be able to see where/how the cookie value is obtained (the cookie value is passed to the `reload()` function). I didn't have the time to spend hunting around to find where it is called, but if you do, then that's probably your best bet

Answer (score 0):

So what actually happens is that the URL you're trying to reach will check if a cookie is set. If not, it will do so and reload. This is not possible through requests because in order to set the cookie it needs to run JavaScript (which Python obviously can't do).

A way around this would be to use the cookies that your browser stores. These are stored in an SQLite database on your system and you can use libraries like `browsercookie` (https://github.com/richardpenman/browsercookie) to access them.

Just do something like:

```py
cookiejar = browsercookie.load()
...
response = session.get(
    "https://we.51job.com/api/job/search-pc?api_key=51job&timestamp=1693104486&keyword=python%20developer&searchType=2&function=&industry=&jobArea=000000&jobArea2=&landmark=&metro=&salary=&workYear=&degree=&companyType=&companySize=&jobType=&issueDate=&sortType=0&pageNum=1&requestId=&pageSize=20&source=1&accountId=&pageCode=sou%7Csou%7Csoulb",
    headers=headers,
    cookies=cookiejar,
)
```

I noticed the site has some security issues related to TLS, which is why I won't post a full working example here (to protect people who simply copy and paste).

Comment: Hey dude, thanks for your time!
Unfortunately this approach doesn't give the cookies needed for what we want, this only provide the cookies that I'm already getting, I need specifically this one: "acw_sc__v2".
But if you found this guy, let me know, because I didn't using the example above and installing browsercookie lib

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

You're having trouble accessing it because you most likely shouldn't be accessing it. It seems pretty clearly to be a security measure against automated scraping.

**Long answer:**

The `acw_sc__v2` cookie is likely a security measure implemented by the website to prevent scraping or automated requests. It's not something that's typically generated on the client-side (i.e., in your Python script), but rather it's set by the server when you make a request to the website.

The value of `acw_sc__v2` is probably a hashed or encrypted string that the server uses to verify the authenticity of the client. It's likely that the server checks this value and if it doesn't match what it expects, it rejects the request.

Unfortunately, without knowing how the server generates this value, it's impossible to replicate it in your script. It's likely that the server uses some combination of your session data, IP address, user agent, and other factors to generate this value.

If you're trying to scrape data from this website, I would recommend looking into their terms of service or contacting them directly to see if they provide a public API or other means of accessing their data. Scraping can be a legal gray area and it's always best to make sure you're in compliance with the website's terms of service.

As a side note, it's also worth mentioning that the `acw_sc__v2` cookie is set with the `HttpOnly` flag, which means it's not accessible via JavaScript. This is a security measure to prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. This doesn't directly affect your Python script, but it's another indication that the server is using this cookie for security purposes.